# cross selling report, dax expression -power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

Good day all,
Pls am new to this and i need help.
I am to find the product pairs(parent code) that sells fast using dax in power bi and the pairs should be ranked 1 to 7 for each parent code. I have a table containing the invoice number, Child number and date. I also have a different table showing the parent code of the child number and the child number. Here are similar tables. My end result should be a table containing the two pair parent codes in separate columns and 3rd column with their rank. Pls the child code is a sub of the parent code. Pls I will appreciate if someone can assist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Qqn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY7m2.png)

I have tried using self join in sql but not getting the right answer. But i need to use dax in power bi, but it seems complicated. Here is how the end result heading of my result will be [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2y5m.png) Thank you